# PyQT5: How to use both QLineEdit: Validator and InputMask?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit, qvalidator

I want to use both InputMask and Validator to get date in the correct form. In the code below I am using InputMask to receive date in format DD.MM.YYYY. I do not know how to limit each part of it (DD, MM and YYYY) because now user can type 40.30.2020 and it is theoretically correct.

```
self.date = QLineEdit(self)
self.date.setInputMask("00.00.0000")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `QDateTimeEdit` Class
>
> The `QDateTimeEdit` class provides a widget for editing dates and times.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QDateTimeEdit, 
                             QFormLayout, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()    

        self.datetime = QDateTimeEdit(QDate.currentDate())

        self.v_layout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.v_layout.addRow(QLabel('DD.MM.YYYY'), self.datetime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]